# iOS MapView shows entire United States

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, mapkit

I'm trying to load a region in a MapView, but I always get a view of the entire U.S. This is an iPad app that runs in landscape mode. I'm thinking that the spans may not be the proper dimensions, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Here's the data I have. Any ideas?

Thanks...[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've solved similar problem by adding CLLocationManager:

```
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    // Check for iOS 8. Without this guard, the code will crash with "unknown selector" on iOS 7.
    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: I am using a CLLocationManager, and it is properly showing the user's location, I just can't get the visible region to set properly.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are attempting to show a user’s location. The span data appears to be correct with respect to the region that you are attempting to display.

In this case, location services will need to be authorized by the user prior to MapKit being able to display the location.

When the location services are not authorized, the map of the United States will show instead of the region that you attempting to display.

Assuming you have a `CLLocationManager` you will need to authorize location services using `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` or `requestAlwaysAuthorization`.

If you have

```
self.locationManager = [CLLocationManager alloc] init];
```

then you will need to call

```
[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
```

or

```
[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
```

These both require that a key of `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` is added to your app's `Info.plist` file.

Comment: I am trying to show the user's location, but that part works properly, I get the blue dot in the right location, but for some reason it isn't setting the region properly. I'm wondering if it could be because the span isn't the right width to height ratio compared to the map. Any ideas?

Comment: @SeanT As far as I know, the two factors to get the region to display are the center and the span. I used 0.001 for both deltas in the lat/long span and I'm able to get into the street level of the map in the US. Have you obtained authorization for your location services? That is something that could prevent zooming into the region.